# Is it possible to access 127.0.0.xxx in anyway

Tags: routing, ip, ipv4, mac-address, ip-address

So I've been configuring my network at work. We've got a lot of devices from NAS servers to Dante AoIP devices.

While configuring some of my devices I managed to set the IP adress of one device to 127.0.0.10 (I wasn't even aware that Dante controller would allow me to do this since windows and Mac both deny you from doing this on your NIC as it's an invalid IP address)
This device isn't running any OS, it's an Audinate Brooklyn II module situated in a Dante capable device.

The problem I have now is that it's in an IP address range I have no access to. If I use Wireshark to scan for packets I can see the device broadcasting RTP packets from 127.0.0.10 which is good as I know the device is on the network, but obviously I can't set the NIC of my computers to the 127 range. It doesn't look like that the Dante module uses 127.0.0.xxx for loopback since it's sending packets

Is there a way I can somehow set my NIC (either on a PC or Mac) to the 127 address range so that I can change the IP address of this module?

Comment: Unfortunately, host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network. In any case, _any_ traffic sent to an address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block will immediately loop back inside the sending host. That is a requirement for IPv4.

Comment: *which is good* Actually, it's spec-illegal. 127/8 **cannot** exist on a physical network. That dante hardware is NOT spec compliant (and it's a spec that's 40 years old.) You should complain as loudly as possible to the manufacturer. NO OS will allow you to violate that part of the spec. (with some hackery, you can make linux/bsd do it, but the Dante software only exists for mac/win)

Comment: See if the Dante device is reachable via IPv6 link-local.